# Misalignment between code and form properties in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I got really mad trying to fix a bug in C# using Visual Studio 2010: when loading an image in a pictureBox control within a panel the image was automatically resized to fill the whole area. The form behavior was as the Dock property was: fill; BUT the Dock property shown in the designer proper panel the was clearly: none, as intended.

Just to make sure, after couple of hours debugging and testing, trying understand, I checked the Mainform.Designer.cs source and, with my greatest surprise, I have found this line of code:

```
this.pictureBox.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
```

I am absolutely sure of what I am saying: I double checked both code and the properties panel. After changing manually (I know that I should not) that line to:

```
this.pictureBox.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.None;
```

all was up and running as designed.

In other words, there was a misalignment between the code and the properties shown in Visual Studio. Now, my question is: is just me, or did someone else already noticed this kind of behavior? Did someone else noted that sometimes the code and what is shown as property by VS are two different things? Or this is due to something incredibly sloppy/wrong/idiot made by me? If explanation is the latter, have some hints about what was possibly wrong (apart me, of course)? If the explanation is the former, there is someone out there programming in C# without Visual Studio and happy?

Thanks for your ideas.

---

Update. The issue exists and surfaces even accessing different parameters. Further details gathered here:

[Trello CS board](https://trello.com/c/k7cr5jid/1-misalignment-between-code-and-form-properties-in-vs-2010)

Comment: It is just you.  Having to choose between "a bug in C#" and you accidentally setting the Dock property and not remembering that you did, I have to favor the latter explanation.  Show us a repro for this.

Comment: Why should you not change properties manually? I never use the properties panel in VS.

Comment: @HansPassant: I do not like to insist and I am trying to detect evidence that it's me (I would be more than happy to discover this, because the solution in this case would be easy) but the problem exists even accessing different parameters. I have gathered some more details in the post edit. Anyways, my VS instance is not integrated with source control.

Comment: @Saggio: well, i am forced to do so, indeed. Otherwise the code do not works as intended. But I would like to understand where the ghost is.

Comment: @Daniel it is strange behavior, but as Rajesh pointed out it might have to do with permissions; perhaps try to create a new solution and import your project(s) but don't commit them to your source control to see if that's the issue.  Otherwise, you can always just get used to setting properties in the code so this becomes a non-issue - I find it easier and much quicker to start typing and use intellisence to find the property I want rather than scrolling through the properties window anyhow ;)

Answer (score 1):

This could happen when you have permission problem with designer.cs.  i.e.  When your code is integrated with Source control, it makes it read only to identify the checked out files.